When vs If, when describing settings and parameters
For a current guide, I'm describing settings of an application where you can toggle the setting from Yes to No.
Which of the following is correct, or better, to use?

When set to Yes, this...
If set to Yes, this...

I assumed When is better to use since the setting will either be Yes or No, however I'm using a reference guide to help write mine and it uses If.

When I write these kinds of things, I sometimes avoid the if/when choice by just starting each "what the setting does" sentence with the setting name: "The option setting can be either Yes or No. Yes does (whatever).... No does (whatever)..."

While 'When' and 'If' can be used interchangeably in your situation, I think that if you were to adopt a specific rubric of when those terms were to be applied, then that consistency would help users develop an understanding of the material.
For instance, if you used 'When' to describe  fixed modes of operation of your system. As in "when in edit mode" or "when in review mode", then that kind of consistency of language can help the user compartmentalize the details. In this example, then if would be relegated to modifiers of those modes. As in 'when editing, if expert mode is enabled, the user can accidently erase all of their work using Alt-Control-J.'
The choice of 'When' and 'If' in my example is reversible. It still works. Its about finding a formalism and sticking with it.
And, another point is that if the documentation reads weird because of too many 'If' and 'When' clauses, then the structure of the documentation might be too informal.  Like too many paragraphs. Using Tiered Headings with Labels like '1.2.3 Edit mode' or ' 1.1.4 Expert mode' might be an approach.

I think a look in a dictionary will answer your question.

when "at what time; at the time at which"
if "used to say that a particular thing can or will happen only after something else happens or becomes true"


Temporal relation
When would be used if something takes place at the time at which your setting is set to "Yes".
Examples:

We will eat when you come.
means: It is certain that you will come and we will eat at the time at which you arrive.


Control Lock: When set to ALL CONTROLS, locks all controls and buttons except the release. (from The Hasselblad Manual)
means: While the control lock is set to ALL CONTROLS...

The focus of the second example is how the camera handles during the time a certain setting is chosen. The viewpoint is that of user experience. The purpose of the control lock is that the user is safe from accidentally changing his or her chosen camera settings while they take photographs.

Logical relation
If would be used if something depends on your setting to be set to "Yes".
Examples:

We will watch the movie if you come.
means: It is uncertain whether you will come or not, and if you don't come, we will not watch the movie without you.


property           description
show-week-numbers  If set to TRUE, the week numbers
                   will be displayed along the left
                   side of the calendar.

                                                        (from Foundations of GTK+ Development)
means: if(show-week-numbers == TRUE) { display week numbers }

The focus of the second example is how the software functions on a programmatical level. The viewpoint is that of the programmer who wants to understand a specific detail of how the application functions. The setting, in this case, isn't even directly accessible to the user: the user doesn't click on that property – there are likely several other steps between the user clicking a button and that property set to TRUE, e.g. a function that listens for the click event, and there are likely other steps between that function set to TRUE and the display of the week number in the calendar. It is also possible, that this property is only TRUE for a brief moment to toggle the display and is unset afterwards, so it may not persist for any user perceptible time period.
